# How to work on multiple files using RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Reason for asking:
This has been a favorite question to interviewers and hence I tried finding an answer to it but have not been able to with whatever available on internet so far

Requirement:
I have two files in the below format, on which I want to do an operation (**ONLY USING RDD**) to find out for each age, how many married, single and divorced people subscribed.

File1:

```
age subscribed
58  no
44  no
33  no
58 yes
```

File 2:

```
age job marital education   default balance
58  management  married tertiary    no  2143
44  technician  single  secondary   no  29
33  entrepreneur    married secondary   no  2
58  management  single  tertiary    no  1387
```

Following is an example output:

```
58 married 0
58 single 1
```

Comment: Why a -ve marking on this ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by doing the followings .

First read both files and parse them to `rdds`

```
val rdd1 = sparkContext
  .textFile("path to first csv")
  .map(_.split(" ").toList)
  .map(list => (list.head, list.tail))
val rdd2 = sparkContext
  .textFile("path to second csv")
  .map(_.split(" ").toList)
  .map(list => (list.head, list.tail))
```

*Paired RDD* is created for `join`ing purpose by `age`.

```
rdd1.join(rdd2).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(values => {
  val subsCount = values.map(x => counts(0, 0, x._2._1(0), x._2._2(1)))
  (subsCount.map(_._1).sum, subsCount.map(_._2).sum)
}).flatMap(x => Array((x._1, "married", x._2._1), (x._1, "single", x._2._2)))
  .foreach(println)
```

where `counts` is a *function*

```
def counts(marriedSubs: Int, singleSubs: Int, subs: String, marrital: String) : Tuple2[Int, Int] = (subs.toLowerCase(), marrital.toLowerCase()) match {
  case ("yes", "married") => (marriedSubs+1, singleSubs)
  case ("yes", "single") => (marriedSubs, singleSubs+1)
  case _ => (marriedSubs, singleSubs)
}
```

You should have following output

```
(58,married,1)
(58,single,1)
(33,married,0)
(33,single,0)
(44,married,0)
(44,single,0)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh Mahajan for the help. It works for me

Comment: my pleasure @RahulMukherjee , thanks for accepting the answer :)